# Bending a CCSprite by Skewing it from various points like in photoshop

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

Hi I am Using Cocos2d with Box2d.

I have a "Stick.png" as CCSprite  Now I want to **bend** it from center downwards and Upwards from the end and start of image.. I am trying to make game like hill Climb  that is using only one Green image of a grass strip for the whole **vehicle** Path/Road used in the game.

I shall be thankful.

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [skewX skewY properties](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest_2.x/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_node.html#a3ab54b6652338e7d575ee14971147cbf) to achieve this effect. There are also CCSkewBy and CCSkewTo actions to animate skewing.

Comment: Yes I have tried Skew Functions but these functions only skew the image all along the x-axis or y-axis  I can not Irregulate the skew Functions.

If you have seen the Hill Climb Game on Android they have a strip of path like a line and they are skewing it from different points  up and down to create hill and steap/pits paths and reusing the texture by skewing it with different values.